# Database enumeration fails on my Azure hosted SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I can connect to my database server (Azure hosted) with SQL Server Management Studio, however I am unable to enumerate its databases.

[image: SSMS Error Dialog]

On the Azure portal, I am seeing a similar issue:

[image: Azure Portal Status]

The fact is, these databases are up and running. My application continues to function. I am also able to issues queries via SSMS Query window. The main problem here is the inability to enumerate databases on the server. If you have any idea how I might solve this, thank you very much for any advice which you can provide!

Comment: The issue resolved itself after about 1 and a half hours. I don't have any root cause though. If you can shed any light on this incident please let me know. That will be helpful in case this recurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the Azure platform. Here is what we received from our hosting provider in response to our inquiry:

**SQL and Open-Source Database Service Management Issues - East US - Mitigated (Tracking ID 8K76-LZ8)**

**Summary of impact:** Between approximately 13:30 and 16:30 UTC on 19 May 2020, a subset of customers in East US may have intermittently experienced timeouts and latency issues when processing service management operations - such as create, update, delete - for SQL resources hosted in this region, including Azure SQL Database and open-source databases such as Azure Database for PostgreSQL, Azure Database for MySQL, and Azure Database for MariaDB. Some customers may have also encountered issues or experienced latency when loading database management tools or expanding database resources in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Retries may have been successful.

**Preliminary root cause:** After an initial investigation, engineers identified that an increased volume of requests had consumed a large number of available private endpoint connections for the SQL control plane in East US, thus leading to failures for subsequent control plane operations in the region.

**Mitigation:** Once the preliminary root cause was identified, engineering teams terminated connections from the source of the increased load.

**Next steps:** We apologize for the impact to affected customers. Engineers will continue to investigate the underlying cause and take steps to prevent future occurrences, which includes:

•   Further investigating and understanding the source of increased workload on the SQL platform

•   Increasing the resiliency of the SQL platform to better account for this type of work volume

[End of Report]

Anyway, I am posting this so that anyone who encounters this issue in the future should know - it may not be your issue. It may be an issue with the Azure hosting platform in which case you will just need to wait until engineers resolve the issue at their end.